# How do I access the terminal over a usb port?

Tags: command-line, usb

I'm relatively new to Ubuntu and Linux as a whole. What I'm trying to do is log into the terminal from a usb port. The cable I have set up is not recognized as a USB device (dmesg shows that it can't be enumerated). Is there a way I can force it to set up a connection? I've tried searching around, but all the solutions I've found rely on the device being recognized already.

Comment: A usb cable is just wires and two connectors - basically, an extension of a usb port, why should it be recognized as a device? What's on the other side of the usb port?

Comment: A MAX3232 chip and a serial port, which then goes to a null modem cable and a terminal.